# calculate variogram/GLCM with a raster output in R

Tags: r, textures, glcm

I'd like to use the geostatistical texture to  classify  my remote sensing data, but I can't find a package that give a result I want---it should result a raster type output, so that I can use it with spectral date (such as TM) in R. I search this for days, nothing useful find. so I need your help.

Comment: Probably http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ better fit for questions like this.

Comment: thanks, I am a new in stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [glcm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glcm/) package - it will handle a raster input and will output GLCM textures as a RasterStack. There is an example [here](http://azvoleff.com/articles/calculating-image-textures-with-glcm/).